# CSS: Making Flexbox Layout static

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, width

I am trying to put some content into a flex layout row and I noticed that

- the row resizes in width with his content

Instead I try to make the width of the row static, so that every child, which is bigger, breaks.

*CodeMirror editor is just used to illustrate the problem of having a bigger and/or smaller children in that row.*

Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pddqrfav/9/)

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  .flex {
    width: 100%;
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: red;
    }
    #wrapper #item {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ce = document.getElementById("item");

var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(node){ce.parentNode.replaceChild(node, ce);}, {
  value: "function myScript(){return 100;}",
  mode:  "javascript",
  lineSeparator: null,
  theme: "default", // theme directory
  indentUnit: 2,
  smartIndent: true,
  tabSize: 2,
  indentWithTabs: false,
  electricChars: true,
  extraKeys: null,
  lineWrapping: false,
  lineNumbers: true,
  firstLineNumber: 1,
  scrollbarStyle: "overlay",
  inputStyle: "contenteditable",
  readOnly: false, // also "nocursor"
  showCursorWhenSelecting: false,
  lineWiseCopyCut: true,
  undoDepth: 200,
  historyEventDelay: 1250,
  autofocus: true
});

});
</script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="flex">ABC</div>
  <div class="flex">
    DEF
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">GHI</div>
</div>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: maybe its obivious, but what do you mean by *so that every child, which is bigger, breaks* ?

Comment: @kukkuz If the child's width is bigger than the width of the flex column, the flex column expands in width to match the width of it's child. I am trying to just limit the width of the child to the width of the flex column. Take a look at the linked Fiddle in the question to see what I mean.

Comment: there are three flex items inside your `main` (the flexbox) *flexed* along the row... so what do you mean by *width of the flex column*? (the width of each flex *item* varies with their content)

Comment: I certainly meant row and not column. In my case I am just building a layout with columns, that's why I misused the word here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **JavaScript** in this. Just get the `width` of the middle flex element (in my case its class is `.codemirror`) & then apply that `width` to itself. Like:

```
// Used setTimeout to get the plugin initialized
setTimeout(function() {
  var codemirror_width = $('.flex.codemirror').width();
  $('.flex.codemirror').css('width', codemirror_width);
}, 100);
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var codemirror_width = $('.flex.codemirror').width();
  $('.flex.codemirror').css('width', codemirror_width);
}, 100);
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}
#main .flex {
  width: 100%;
}
#main .flex:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
#main .flex #wrapper #item {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.20.2/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var ce = document.getElementById("item");
  
    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(node){ce.parentNode.replaceChild(node, ce);}, {
      value: "function myScript(){return 100;}",
      mode:  "javascript",
      lineSeparator: null,
      theme: "default", // theme directory
      indentUnit: 2,
      smartIndent: true,
      tabSize: 2,
      indentWithTabs: false,
      electricChars: true,
      extraKeys: null,
      lineWrapping: false,
      lineNumbers: true,
      firstLineNumber: 1,
      scrollbarStyle: "overlay",
      inputStyle: "contenteditable",
      readOnly: false, // also "nocursor"
      showCursorWhenSelecting: false,
      lineWiseCopyCut: true,
      undoDepth: 200,
      historyEventDelay: 1250,
      autofocus: true
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="flex">ABC</div>
  <div class="flex codemirror">
    DEF
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="item">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">GHI</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a great solution in itself! But is it possible to set `max-width` to the initial `width` of the flex column. That's what I am trying to do, so the column shouldn't resize at all when the content changes :)

Comment: @jonhue Try using `min-width`. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Problem with that is, that it manipulates the initial width of the flex column and sort of defeats the purpose of using a flex layout

Comment: @jonhue You need to use **JS** for this. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I think I was wrong. If I use `1%` for example as `min-width` it works. It just feels a little hacky.

Comment: The javascript solution obviously like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Its my pleasure @jonhue .  jQuery makes everything so simple!! :)